# LineTraceSingleByChannel(HitResult, Start, End, ECollisionChannel::ECC_Visibility) does not hit character mesh and other static meshes

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm trying to make a raycast by using Line trace by channel using ECC_Visibility channel.But the problem is the line trace hits all the brushes in the level but when i shoot at character or any other static meshes it goes through them without hitting them.How can I solve this problem because When i shoot at AI enemy it goes through it instead of hitting it.I tested it by using a player charcter mesh.

When i shoot at the player character mesh it goes through it and does not hit it.

My collision preset for capsule component

[image]

Collision preset for character mesh

[image]

```
    void AShooterCharacter::Fire()
    {
     
        /*Attach muzzleflash particle effect to Muzzle_01 socket of Gun
        GetMesh() is to get the parent of the gun mesh i.e wraith character mesh which has gun by default*/
        UGameplayStatics::SpawnEmitterAttached(MuzzleFlash, GetMesh(), TEXT("Muzzle_01"));
     
     
        /*Get the starting location and rotation of the Line trace which is the Muzzle_)1 socket location
        in the gun attached to wraith mesh*/
     
        FVector Start = GetMesh()->GetSocketLocation(TEXT("Muzzle_01"));
     
        /*The rotation is important to make the line trace to go at proper direction at all rotation*/
        FRotator StartRotation = GetMesh()->GetSocketRotation(TEXT("Muzzle_01"));
        
     
        /*The end location of line trace is start  added with the rotation Vector() gives forward vector in any 
        rotation multiplied by range(100.0f)*/
        FVector End = Start + ( StartRotation.Vector()* Range);
     
     
        //Debug line
        DrawDebugLine(GetWorld(), Start, End, FColor::Green, false, 1.0f, 0, 1.0f);
     
     
        FHitResult HitResult;
     
    //  FCollisionQueryParams params;
     
        //params.AddIgnoredActor(this->GetOwner());
     
     
        bool DidHit = GetWorld()->LineTraceSingleByChannel(HitResult, Start, End, ECollisionChannel::ECC_Visibility);
     
        if (DidHit)
        {
            UStaticMeshComponent* HitMesh = Cast<UStaticMeshComponent>(HitResult.GetActor()->GetRootComponent());
     
            if (HitMesh && HitResult.GetActor()->IsRootComponentMovable())
            {
                UGameplayStatics::SpawnEmitterAtLocation(GetWorld(),ImpactEffect,HitResult.Location);
     
                HitMesh->AddImpulse(FVector(1, 0, 0) * ImpulseAmount);
     
                
            }
        }
     
     
    }
```

Comment: Your Collision Component is set to ignore Visibility...

Comment: I tried and changed it to block and also tried block all but it doesn’t seem to work

Comment: And also I tried by placing a static mesh cube from starter content initially the line trace didn’t hit the cube but later I changed it to simulate physics then the line trace hit the cube and applied impulse but it didn’t work with a skeletal mesh

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using Camera chanel instead of Visible

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).